# Django REST: Create a model object with the user field as current user

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, axios

I have a Document model which has user field as a ForeignKey. I'm trying to implement two very common features:

1. user creates a new document withCredentials=True; the document will of course have the owner as the user that created it
2. user can later fetches all documents that have the owner as themselves

This is my current code. I am assuming I got the model fields correct as I can see the User field as a dropdown menu in the admin panel. However, I am not sure which part (backend vs frontend) I need to modify in order to allow frontend to make an AXIOS POST request.

### BACKEND (DJANGO REST FRAMEWORK)

models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
    id = HashidAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Untitled")
    template = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    editorState = models.JSONField(default=[])
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = HashidSerializerCharField(source_field="documents.Document.id", read_only=True)
    question_blocks = QuestionBlockSerializer(many=True)
    outline_blocks = OutlineBlockSerializer(many=True)
    mysource = MySourceSerializer(many=True)
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        question_blocks = validated_data.pop("question_blocks")
        outline_blocks = validated_data.pop("outline_blocks")
        document = Document.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for qBlock in question_blocks:
            QuestionBlock.objects.create(document=document, **qBlock)
        for oBlock in outline_blocks:
            OutlineBlock.objects.create(document=document, **oBlock)
        document.save()
        return document
```

users/models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    username = None
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="unknown")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="unknown")
    profile_pic = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="unknown")

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, db_index=True)
    secret_key = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=get_random_secret_key)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        swappable = "AUTH_USER_MODEL"

    # objects = CustomUserManager()
    @property
    def name(self):
        if not self.last_name:
            return self.first_name.capitalize()

        return f"{self.first_name.capitalize()} {self.last_name.capitalize()}"
```

### FRONTEND (REACT)

```
export const createDocTemp = ({
  router,
  title,
  templateId,
  question_blocks,
  outline_blocks,
}: NewDocument) => {
  const data = {
    user =====================================> what should go here?
    title,
    templateId,
    question_blocks,
    outline_blocks,
  };
  console.log(data);
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/v1/documents/`,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    data,
    withCredentials: true,
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      if (response.status === 201) {
        router.push(`/draft/${response.data.id}/`);
      }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error.toJSON());
    });
};
```

Even though I set the user field as not-required, I am constantly getting 400 error for the function above. I can't see the exact error message since I couldn't replicate "withCredentials" part in my postman.

Answer (score 0):

in serializers, you send the id of the user

```
const data = {
    user =====================================> ID (1,22,44,etc) of user
    title,
    templateId,
    question_blocks,
    outline_blocks,
  };
```

And secondly, you have two remove the **read_only** param from *DocumentSerializer*

```
class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = HashidSerializerCharField(source_field="documents.Document.id", read_only=True)
    question_blocks = QuestionBlockSerializer(many=True)
    outline_blocks = OutlineBlockSerializer(many=True)
    mysource = MySource
```

Serializer(many=True)

```
class Meta:
    model = Document
    fields = "__all__"

def to_representation(self, instance):
    response = super().to_representation(instance)
    response['user'] = UserSerializer(instance.user).data
    return response
```

Comment: removing read_only gives the following error: "Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`."